# Bibliography causes errors when compiling

Tags: bibliographies, citing

When using the achemso LaTeX package, the citations always appear as question marks - it's a problem that happens on Ubuntu and Mac machines, but works fine with Windows machines. Our research group here are working on the same .tex document with the same .bib file and sharing via a Bitbucket repository.

We all use TeXstudio as our LaTeX editor.

Uses the latest version of MacTeX on Mac (25 May 2014 distribution) and TexLive on Ubuntu (version 2013.2014 0215-1). The Windows machine is using MiKteX (version 2.9.5105).

I have attached a screenshot of the issues we have when compiling on Mac and Ubuntu.

Thank you very much! :)!

The link to the .bib file is here: lab.tiggalina.net/Levy_FCC_tort.bib
The link to the .tex file is here: http://lab.tiggalina.net/Levy%20FCC%20tortuosity.tex
And, the link to the .png file is: lab.tiggalina.net/lion.png

Thank you very much :)

[Screenshot of issues.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nBP2S.png)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Hi and welcome, side question: TeX Live is available for so many architectures, why aren't you using TeX Live for all your installations? Add `\listfiles`  to the top of your doc and compare the different file lists.

Comment: Thanks, @DG' - I have included the links to the files in the original post now... didn't know how else to put them on here so hopefully you guys can see them now.

Thanks, Johannes_B, but adding the \listfiles command doesn't seem to do anything different in my document...

Thank you :)

Comment: This looks very similar to what you've already said in comments on http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/227961/how-to-install-the-achemso-package-on-mac-os-x-yosemite. As I said there, you need to run LaTeX, BibTeX, LaTeX, LaTeX: this may well happen automatically with MiKTeX.

Comment: I am aware of that, thank you, @JosephWright. Unfortunately it didn't work. But it appears as though having spaces in the title of the files messes with it!
Thanks for your help, though!

Comment: Are there news here?

Comment: Yep, as I said in my previous comment, changing the files names helped!